# NodeJS Mongoose updateOne giving no match every time

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to update a document in mongo with mongoose using updateOne method:

```
const updateResult = await UserModel.updateOne({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)
}, {
    $set: {
        a: 'B'
    }
})
```

- userId contains a string of the ID of the user.

I have tried using the following

```
       1. { _id: userId }
       2. { email: theEmailOfTheUser }
```

But still, the updateResult is

```
 n:0, nModified:0,  ok:0
```

So I think it's must be something with the method itself and not in my query.

Also, when I'm trying to find the user using the query below, it can find it:

```
const user = await UserModel.find({
        _id: userId
    });
//user is found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually mongoose takes care of the `$set` and you do not have to add it. just:

```
const updateResult = await UserModel.updateOne({
    _id: userId
}, {
    a: 'B'
})
```

but the better solution would to just use `findByIdAndUpdate()`:

```
const updateResult = await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
    a: 'B'
})
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if I have to $push?

Comment: I think you would have to find the doc first and the update it manually.

Comment: Actually $push worked as expected (instead of $set)

Comment: nice :D did not know that!